# How does requestAnimationFrame compare to forcing the browser to re-compute an element's style?

Tags: javascript

Often times it's useful to force the browser to re-compute the CSS of a given element via JavaScript.

For instance, from the guide [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36):

```
snowFlake.style.transform = 'translate(' + snowLeft + 'px, -100%)';
// wait a frame
snowFlake.offsetWidth;
snowFlake.style.transitionProperty = 'transform';
snowFlake.style.transitionDuration = '1500ms';
snowFlake.style.transform = 'translate(' + snowLeft + 'px, ' + window.innerHeight + 'px)';
```

This example calls `snowFlake.offsetWidth` in order to force the browser to recognize the recently modified transform property. The browser would not transition the snowFlake without this delay.

I'm curious how this solution stacks up compared to:

```
snowFlake.style.transform = 'translate(' + snowLeft + 'px, -100%)';
// wait a frame
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    snowFlake.style.transitionProperty = 'transform';
    snowFlake.style.transitionDuration = '1500ms';
    snowFlake.style.transform = 'translate(' + snowLeft + 'px, ' + window.innerHeight + 'px)';
});
```

In practice, this seems to work as expected. However, I'm unsure if that is just coincidence.

Have I introduced a race condition with this implementation? Or, does this solution work as expected, but in a non-blocking fashion? If not, what's going on behind the scenes with calculating offsetWidth that requestAnimationFrame does not encompass?

Comment: Without any “interruption” you would not see any transition, because the first and second change to the `translate` property would be executed within the same “cycle”, so that the second one just overwrites the first one before control is even handed back to the rendering engine. Querying `offsetWidth` makes a request to the rendering engine necessary however, to ask about the actual width of that element – and thereby “breaks” the cycle.

Comment: It is/was also common to achieve the same thing by doing the second CSS property manipulation using `setTimeout` – which also results in control being handed back to the rendering engine, before JS becomes active again to execute the code delayed by the (minimal) timeout.

Comment: @CBroe Could you provide some sources? I am confused as to how requestAnimationFrame could execute within the same 'cycle.' What are the conditions for requestAnimationFrame's callback being executed?

Comment: The point is _not_ executing the second property manipulation within the same “cycle”. I use the term “cycle” loosely here, it is not specified as such anywhere to my knowledge; however, the general thing is that once you execute some JS code, the JS engine of the browser “takes over” and only hands control back to the rendering engine when it is done executing all code. Reading a value that needs asking the rendering engine to be determined (such as the actual width of an element), using a timeout or requesting an animation frame all break that cycle (albeit in slightly different ways maybe).

Comment: Okay. It sounds like we're in agreement. It would seem like it would be better to store code which is dependent on the next 'cyce' inside of a callback to allow other JavaScript to continue execution rather than forcing the browser to 'cycle' immediately via asking for offsetWidth. Yes?

Comment: Not sure if it makes such a big difference as to what method you actually chose (as long as you don’t have a _lot_ of other stuff going on at the same time as well); but yes, if you have other JS code following that, `requestAnimationFrame` might be the better idea (or `setTimeout`, that should achieve the same thing in that regard). As to why exactly `requestAnimationFrame` makes it behave that way, I am not really sure right now; I’ll try and find something in the specs about that.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#introduction actually mentions setTimeout (although rather in context of general animation via script, so setting new values for a CSS property multiple times with a short delay in between, whereas in the case we have here the animation is done via the `transition` property and only _triggered_ via script). I am still not sure though whether `requestAnimationFrame` is actually _reliable_ in what you are trying to achieve here, or if the result is pure coincidence.

Comment: As the spec says, `requestAnimationFrame` appends the callback to the end of the _“animation frame request callback list”_ – but I am not sure whether there might be edge cases where that callback will get executed still within the same “frame” as the first manipulation of the CSS property.